# Splitting 4d array into 3d Arrays

Tags: matlab

I have a 4D matrix of size: `50 x 180 x 320 x 3`

where the first dimension is nothing but an index to choose from 50 pictures, the other three dimensions `180 x 320 x 3` represent an image. for example (3,:,:,:) is my third image and so on...
now I want to plot images using `image` function (or any other plot function), problem is it only accepts 2D or 3D matrices. how can I plot this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`squeeze(your_array(n,:,:,:))` will give you the `n`th image as a 3d array.  You should be able to pass it to `image()`.

Do you want to plot all the images in a grid or something?

Comment: I'd also recommend using `squeeze`. So the command would be `squeeze(your_array(n,:,:,:))`.